# How to check my HDD's for defects

Tags: server, hard-drive

Because I had some problems with my server I want to check it's hard drives for defects (the drives not the file system) which tool can I use for this in ubuntu?

I know for my hard drives there is a CD from Western Digital (Data Lifeguard) but I can't get it to run via usb CD drive. So are there any native alternatives?

**System Information:**

- Acer easyStore h341
- Intel Atom D410 1.66GHz
- 2x 1TB Western Digital Caviar Green (WD10EADS-00P6B0)
- 2x 1TB Western Digital Caviar Green (WD10EADS-22M2B0)
- RAM 2GB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If disks support [SMART](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.), you can try [`smartctl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=smartctl&op=&cx=003883529982892832976:5zl6o8w6f0s&cof=FORID:9&ie=UTF-8&siteurl=manpages.ubuntu.com/) (from package smartmontools).

```
sudo smartctl -d <ata,scsi, etc... > -H /dev/sd*
```

In addition to (not instead of) `smartctl`, or in the unlikely event that the disks do not support SMART, you can test the drive for physical/magnetic damage using the [`badblocks`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=badblocks&op=&cx=003883529982892832976:5zl6o8w6f0s&cof=FORID:9&ie=UTF-8&siteurl=manpages.ubuntu.com/) utility.

Comment: Does this really check the disk or just read the SMART status? Because the SMART status can be fine even though the drive isn't working properly.

Comment: only smart tests will be done

Comment: badblocks looks like the tool i was looking for thank you!

Comment: the command above only reads the SMART status, but the tool can perform tests to hd too. Check its man page, specially the `-t`  switch.

Comment: Or you can use the gui disk utility to run the smart tests.