# Ubuntu 14 Installed on External Hard Drive Random Crashes

Tags: hard-drive, crash

I have installed Ubuntu 14 onto my external hard drive and everything initially works great. However after an apparently random amount of time (although this has happened every time I have been running Ubuntu on the hard drive) everything completely freezes and I have to do a hard restart.

Can anyone suggest any reasons why this might be happening or how I can go about fixing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes) or [How to check my HDD's for defects](http://askubuntu.com/questions/79956/how-to-check-my-hdds-for-defects)

Comment: You are not using NFS by chance, do you?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have fixed the problem by opening the NVIDIA X Server Settings application and changing the graphics profile from NVIDIA to Intel, but thanks for the other answers.

Comment: Try [edit]ing it to make the thank you at the end?