# System dramatically slowed down suddenly

Tags: boot, xubuntu

Today when I booted my pc (Xubuntu 20.04) it took so much time to boot up. It took like 45 minutes to boot up. Normally it takes about 1.5 minutes. When it booted up it was very slow,too(It takes about 40-50 seconds to open up terminal). Before I shutdown yesterday there was no problem at all. I didn't install anything on my last session so I have no idea what may be causing this problem.

Then i tried to boot up live from my usb which also has xubuntu 20.04. It booted up normally and it's speed is normal. There is no problem at all.

Then I booted again to my normal installation. It again took about 45 minutes. Then I tried  `sudo apt update`
`sudo apt upgrade` It took 30 minutes to install 1 MB update. This also changed nothing.

What may have caused the problem?
What may be the solutions?
Is my best go backing up the home directory and formatting and reinstalling?(I'm planning to install Xubuntu 20.04 again)
Lastly I have some programs installed in /opt (the programs I installed from source code). Would backing up the /opt directory and copying it back in the new installation's /opt directory work?

Comment: Do you have xubuntu installed on a SSD or HDD?
If it is installed on a HDD, try to clone all data onto a SSD with WinPE running from DVD, CD or USB.

Comment: I don't have SSD I only use HDD. I don't think this slowness has something to do with HDD slowness because I have been using HDD for all my life

Comment: @FearoftheDark often times a slowdown is of a system is an early warning sign of a dying hard-disk - to have a first glimpse you can open `disks` (you might find it under Accessories) select the disk in the left pane and then click on the three dots in the top and select "SMART DATA & Self-Tests" have a look at the "Type" column. Perhaps share a screenshot
Anyhow you should pick up a live-stick and make a backup if you ain't got a current one!

Comment: this might be helpful if you want to try the command-line https://askubuntu.com/questions/79956/how-to-check-my-hdds-for-defects?rq=1

Comment: All of a sudden the problem is solved by it's own the next day. I booted and everything was back to normal. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Try changing to a SSD. SSD has faster read/write speeds. Also your boot will be much faster and you will have more battery life (longer).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to run fsck to make sure your hard disk is healthy. Do not run fsck on a mounted device, you will need to unmount the target first to avoid damage to your files.

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb
sudo fsck /dev/sdb
```

You can use -p to allow fsck to automatically apply repairs.

```
sudo fsck -p /dev/sdb
```